# How do I prove I am the only owner of an ip address so that no one else can associate it with other domain names?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

Let's say I am assigned with Class C IP addresses block by APNIC. How do I prove I am the only owner of those ip addresses when setting up domain name in DNS? Let's say I use one of those ip addresses to host a website with a domain name I purchase and someone else could use this ip address and associate it with another domain name in DNS,
is it just no one wants to do this because there is no benefit of doing this as it promote other's people's webiste, which is like "deposit money into other people's bank account", and most malicious hackers want to hijack the traffic to their webiste (therefore they pick up domain names which are very similar to the real domain name to confuse people)
But it still sounds weird if it is doable, for example, my opponents can associate domain name like `ComanyXXXIsRubbish.com` with my ip address and harm my company's reputation?

Comment: The only way you can keep the IP is to pay for a static IP or block and ensure payment all the time. There is not any other guarantee.

Comment: @secondimage - No; Because if you own a domain you probably are publishing it to the same DNS that everyone uses, and if your not doing that, it doesn’t matter because it’s not accessible outside of your intranet. Trustworthiness comes from the certificate and the certificate itself, the owner of the domain, is the only individual who can get a certificate linked to the domain that is trusted by default. Google.com is a “safe” website because its reputation is trusted, it’s secure because of the encrypted connection between you and Google, remember secure != safe

Comment: if you set up your http server correctly, it should only serve your domain(s), so if `numpty.com` points to your IP, your http server would not respond with your website. Not sure why anyone would do such a thing, it's not like they magically get some extra access to your data

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, you do not. DNS makes no assertions about how IPs can be used by their registrants, or really anyone else. No one is going to ask you to prove ownership of an IP on any existing TLD. Some day there may be a TLD that requires it, but they will have their work cut out for them if they want to maintain that service.

DNS is just a naming service. its only job is to host zones containing names and to map those names to addresses. As such, registrants own the names they register, and control what is done with those names. Control of the underlying IP addresses however are out of scope for DNS for many, many reasons.

Names are always an abstraction on top of addresses. this allows things like split-horizon lookup, disaster recovery cut-over, load-balanced web-farms, shared-hosting where one IP hosts many sites owned by many owners, Geo-located services that have servers all over the world, CDN caching, etc. All these variant forms of name mapping allow us to host our services in myriad ways, that are enabled by the idea that IPs come and go, but names are flexible in where they point.

Instead, in response to your concern, most organizations restrict their services tier, so that it knows the name(s) it should respond to. Not all services implement features that include known names (it must be communicated in the application layer datagram), but for those that do (including HTTP/S, FTPS, SMTP/IMAP, and many more), the service can be configured to require a HOST or SNI or similar field in the header that identifies the domain name that the client is attempting to connect to. This is usually accomplished using Certificates that are only valid for the domains they are issued for.

Additionally for some protocols, Application Layer Gateways (ALGs) can be implemented to filter traffic based on a domain name in the application layer data. These include sophisticated network firewalls, application reverse proxies, and enterprise-grade load balancers.